# There are no hotels in Thelos!

Tags: zenith-the-game

I am currently ~4 hours into "[Zenith](http://zeniththegame.com/)". I've recently infiltrated the Mages' sactuary/stronghold. After completing that particular segment, the game objective is now:

[image: Meet Alana]

> Meet Alana at the hotel in Thelos

The Thelos city consists of a Palace, 2 fountains/parks and a vendors' street. I can not see **any** hotels there. However, there's a building named Windmill (shown below), but the guard there says that it is currently not open!

[image: Fargus Windmill]

**So where is this hotel?**

Comment: Done. Added the requested Tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damn! The route to hotel is from inside the palace itself. :/ Just after you walk into the palace gates, go to the staired archway to the left-hand side of your screen.

[image: hotel at the left]